# Why javascript condition is getting executed even though the condition is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The javascript flow is entering `if` condition even if the condition is `false`. The code is below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkCon = "teststr2";
    console.log("checkCon: "+checkCon);

    if(checkCon == "teststr") {
        console.log("slakdfjaskldjlk");
        $.ajax({
            url : "OnlineForm",
            data : {                                                 
                "RefId" : Ref
            },
            success : function(response) {
            }
        });

     }
});
</script>
```

Let me know if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: If what is false?

Comment: previously there was a condition but just for testing I replaced it with false, then also same problem

Comment: Is the code within the `if (false) { ... }` block executed, even though the condition is false?

Comment: Yes, and I have check the code visual code studio and it is showing no error in the code

Comment: The code you've posted is broken so could you edit your answer with all the closing brackets needed. If you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can debug the code ourselves and will be able to help easier.

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` for your `success` handler function

Comment: Sorry, I will paste the entire code

Comment: could you post Ref too?

Comment: I have pasted the entire code carefully with every curly bracket checked.

Comment: Could it be in your code that you had `checkCon = "teststr"` instead of `checkCon == "teststr"`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible because i have tested the code in browsers console look at that once [image]

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is correct, then you should see in the console:

```
Console:
"checkCon: teststr2"
"slakdfjaskldjlk"
```

I assume you are seeing this?

I have never seen that happen where JavaScript evaluates true for a different result.  Could you check any other execution points and see if something could be changing that variable in between?

I tried setting up a sample on CodePen; see this sample which mimics the code above without the AJAX call... it only hits the first condition.

[image: Sample JS Code]